# how to move from animation to an activity in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, animation, android-activity

In my project/test app so far I have managed to implement an animation from Lottie animations that displays without any problem. But when the animation is over it doesnt change to another activity. It simply just stays on screen.

Been trying to figure out how to make it so that once the animation has finished,it will automatically be moved to the main fragment ( with Username, password ect) but so far I cant figure it out.

Anyone got a solution/ tips ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GlobeActivity.kt

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }, 3000)
```

Comment: I cant seem to get it going, how would you write it using my values and id ? https://gyazo.com/b8a92ea07c43fa076ebf8a9211594987 - This represent the "Flash" activity with the animation. This represent my main activity: https://gyazo.com/49b579b79d179bf6da172cbf52bcdc1a

Comment: I tried to use it but without success, I attached 2 images showing my code so hopefully you can see what is written so far and how I can implement your code in mine! Thanks

Comment: Can you try again.I rearranged the code

Comment: Now it works but instead of showing the animation, it takes me directly to MainActivity. Is there  a way to delay so that it transfer the user to MainActivity after the animation is completed ?

Comment: how long does the animation take

Comment: I updated my answer again. You change the number 3000 to that animation duration

Comment: if the code works for you please click the checkmark

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works perfect! It transitions to MainActivity after Animation on GlobeActivity is done :D Thank you again and hope you have a good day/Holiday! :)

Comment: you're welcome dear. You can contact me if you need anything.I am Turkish I hope my English is good

Comment: Thanks, will do! and your english is very good, I understand you perfectly :D